# Is there any way to delete a folder in run time if the memory of any file inside the folder is being used

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller, operating-system, delete-file

```
if (Directory.Exists("BarCodePNG"))
{
    Directory.Delete("BarCodePNG", true);
}

if (Directory.Exists("BarCodeJPG"))
{
    Directory.Delete("BarCodeJPG", true);
}

if (Directory.Exists("BarCodeJoinJPG"))
{
    Directory.Delete("BarCodeJoinJPG", true);
}

if (Directory.Exists("output.pdf"))
{
    Directory.Delete("output.pdf", true);
}
```

The error is

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file '2072675160.png' because it is being used by another process.'

Where as I want the folder to be force deleted

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen to the file that is in use and the application that is using it? Why is the file being used in the first place? Is it your application that has it open? If so then you should just close it.

Comment: Windows has a lot of safety build in to prevent that. And for good reason: it's a bad idea and can lead to data corruption. With Linux, as an super user, you can delete everything.

Comment: You can 1. lookup which processes locking a file and kill these processes or 2. flag the files and folders for deletion on reboot and then reboot the machine

Answer (score 0):

//I think you need to close the running data before executing the delete code

```
string location = new Uri(window.LocationURL).LocalPath;
if (string.Equals(location, @"C:\close\me", 
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            window.Quit();
```